# GDAL Convert to GPX, force format

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, gpx

In QGIS 3.16.9, I'm trying to do a simple processing modeler that would repair and convert polygons into simple lines then into GPX files.

First steps are done until I try to save the lines output as a GPX.
I tried using `gdal:convertformat` but whatever I write in the tool in the creation options, such as :

```
-f "GPX" -dsco "GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES" -lco "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

Once I execute the model, the GDAL command always starts by assigning a Geopackage format

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -f "GPX" -dsco "GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=YES" -lco "FORCE_GPX_TRACK=YES" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

How can I change this behavior ?

Comment: -f is output file format, you have `-f "GPKG" -f "GPX"`, AFAIK you can have only one output file.

Comment: I did not write -f "GPKG", it appears only when I execute  the algorithm.